# sync function syntax

Tags: javascript, truffle-test

What is the difference between this syntax:

```
beforeEach( async () => {
   ...
});
```

and this one:

```
beforeEach(async function() {
   ...
});
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is two different ways to define a function:

- The first one is the so-called arrow function, introduced by [ECMAScript 6](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_es6.asp)
- The second one is the classic function in JavaScript.

In most of the cases they are both equivalent, but there are a few features only applicable to the arrow functions (don't have their own `this`, not hoisted and have to be defined before they are used).